# RSA encryption with private key and decryption with a public key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, authentication

When using the RSA cryptosystem, does it still work if you instead encrypt with the private key and decrypt with the public key? What about in the case of using RSA for sender authentication?

Comment: It works, but it is not secure. Don't do it.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann thank you, but what I meant is that does the private key encryption in RSA is exclusively applied in sender authentication? because RSA is a public key cryptography and the encryption is done with a public key rather than a private key.

Comment: Encryption with the private key is part of RSA signatures. But just like we don't use plain RSA for encryption, we don't use plain RSA for signing. Actual signature schemes use padding and hashing.

Comment: @HumamShbib: Your question is too vague for an answer. However, computing ${\tilde m}^d\bmod n$ (where $\tilde m$ is a _padded_ representative of message $m$, $d$ is the private exponent, and $n$ is the public modulus) is used a part of RSA signature of message $m$, including sometime for the purpose of sender authentication. See [PKCS#1](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) or [ISO/IEC 9796-2](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec9796-2%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf) for proper signature schemes.

Comment: @fgrieu I would not point to 9796 unless it is absolutely necessary, there are too many pitfalls

Comment: BTW, if you disclose the modulus of the RSA key pair to multiple parties, and then use a public key with a standardized exponent (3 or the fourth number of Fermat, 65537) for decryption, then **anybody** can decrypt the message. You should at least use a fully randomized exponent, but there are still pitfalls (e.g. padding, as mentioned) if you do.

Comment: @CodesInChaos *But just like we don't use plain RSA for encryption, we don't use plain RSA for signing.* Could you give any reference?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Check [PKSC#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) for secure padding schemes.

Comment: Since no one mentioned it so far: By definition of the encryption scheme, the modulus $n$ is part of the public key. If you just have $d$ and no $n$, you can't "encrypt". About interchangeable $e$ and $d$: Yes it works, but usually $e$ is chosen to be small. This is okay. An easy to guess $d$ is not.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Mathematically it work just fine. "Encrypt" with the private key, "decrypt" with the public key. Typically, however, we say **sign** with the private key and **verify** with the public key.

As stated in the comments, it isn't just a straight forward signing of the message $m$. Typically a hash function and padding is involved. Also, often one has a [separate key pair for signing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133246).

As you can see, there are a number of caveats, but in general you are correct, it is used for sender authentication.

Comment: I'm probably splitting hairs, but "encrypt with the private key" is not a valid cryptographic operation. That usually get translated into a Signature Scheme with Recovery (or indicates that's what the OP wants).

Comment: Encryption is done with public key only, since the key is public, and only the holder of private key can decrypt it. If message is encrypted with private key, then everyone can decrypt it, since the public key is public. The point of encryption is that only the authorized recipient is to get the message, otherwise there's no point encrypting the message; save the time & computing resources, and just display the message to the public!

Answer (score 27):

Asymmetric encryption and signing are entirely distinct concepts. The security and construction requirements are completely different. (Encryption for instance, needs to be an injection, whereas signature verification needs to be a surjection towards the verified message space. As a further hint of how they are intrinsically different, note that it lasted quite a bit of time before ID-based encryption could be designed, whereas ID-based signatures were there from the beginning.)

To put it simply: there is no meaning for (understand definition for) the wording "encrypt with the private key". How would you do it?

By way of example, take the ElGamal encryption scheme: $s$ is your private key, $g^s$ your public key. To encrypt $m$, you draw a random $r$ and compute the ciphertext $(g^r,m*g^{r*s})$. Now, let's be practical: you've got this nice library implementing ElGamal. The API for encryption says the function takes two arguments: a message and a public key, that is a group element $g^s$ for some secret number $s$ and some group generator $g$. Now how do you "encrypt with the private key" $s$? You feed the function with $m$ and $s$? It does not comply with the API and it might even crash.
Then let's be theoretical: how do you sign with the ElGamal encryption?

Eventually, this misconception probably arise from the specifics of the underlying mathematical structure of RSA (which has both signature and encryption variants, and where a private key of the same form can be used for decryption or signature, and the corresponding public key used for encryption of signature verification). But even there, a standard-compliant implementation will not allow you to "decrypt with the public key". Due to padding indeed, there is no way decryption will succeed. For the particular case of RSA, see also [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123).

So if you need to sign, use the signing function of a signature scheme with a private key.
And if you need to encrypt, use the encryption function of an encryption scheme with a public key. After all, that's what they were designed for.

Comment: Why does a signature need to be a surjection? Does that mean that every byte-string of a given length should be a valid signature of something?

Comment: I meant, the public function in an encryption scheme must basically be an injection (so that one can always decrypt) whereas the public function in a signature scheme must basically be a surjection (so that one can always sign).

Answer (score 23):

The two keys $(e,m)$ and $(d,m)$ in the RSA key pair are fully equivalent, in that $e$ and $d$ can be arbitrarily chosen integers (in the interval $0..m-1$) as long as they fulfill the well-known congruence $ed \equiv 1 \mod \phi(m)$. You can swap them and nothing will change.

A key becomes `public` the moment you (as the key generator) decide to disclose it, possibly to attackers too. By consequence, the one you decide **not** to disclose becomes the `private` key.

When you use the key pair for **confidentiality** purposes, you typically want everybody to be able to send confidential messages to a receiver, so that only such receiver can interpret them. In such case, everybody shares a key (which will be the `public` one by the definition above, used for **encryption**), whereas the receiver has got the one which is not shared with anybody else (which must be the `private` key, used for **decryption**).

The idea of using the `public` key for decryption undermines the very purpose of having a scheme in place for confidentiality as defined above. Why should you do encryption at all if anybody (including the attacker) can undo it?

If you are thinking "*Maybe I could securely distribute the public key only to the intended receiver*", then you are not disclosing any key at all, and the definition of `public` and `private` do not hold anymore: you use RSA as a sort of secret key cipher like AES.

On the other hand, when you use the key pair for **authentication** purposes, you typically want everybody (including any forger) to be able to establish with certainty that a message really comes from a certain originator, and not from anybody else. In such case, everybody shares a key (which is again the `public` one, used for **verification**), whereas the originator has got the one which is not disclosed to anybody else (which must be the `private` key, used for **signing**).

In the same way as before, using the `public` key for signing is contradictory.

Finally, it should be noted that the `public` key (in either case) takes a special form (`3`, `65537`, etc). That is purely for efficiency purposes (since the key must be `public` anyway, why don't we pick one that is computationally easy to deal with?), and it is not related to security.